# How to know when I last changed my Windows 10 password?

Tags: windows-10, password-management

How to find out when I last changed the password for my account in Windows 10?

Comment: Dou you think something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46571762/list-last-windows-password-change-for-all-users-on-a-non-domain-system ?

Comment: This is a really good question. It's nice to be able to know _just_ my password-change dates, and not those for everyone on the AD.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the [Net User](https://ss64.com/nt/net-useradmin.html) command to display the date and time you last set your **Windows 10** user account password. Check the **Password last set** output of the `net user %username%` command.

---

**Local Account Command**

```
net user %username%
```

[image]

**Domain Account Command**

**Note:** *Use if logged onto a domain joined PC you're logged on with a domain account*

```
net user %username% /domain
```

---

### Further Resources

- [Net User](https://ss64.com/nt/net-useradmin.html)